# SMD for categorical variable using tbl_summary

Tags: gtsummary, smd

The gtsummary::tbl_summary functionality is wonderful and I am looking for a way to add SMD for categorical variables. The tableone function provided smd for all types of covariates including character.
I tried adding SMD to tbl_summary by add_stat with effsize::cohen.d or effsize::cohen.d.
but both worked for numeric covariates and not for character.
Any guidance is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the `add_difference()` function with method `"smd"` to get the standardized mean differences. Review this page for a list of all available methods https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tests.html

```r
library(gtsummary)
#> #Uighur
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.2'

tbl <- 
  trial %>%
  select(trt, age, response, grade) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt, missing = "no") %>%
  add_difference(everything() ~ "smd")
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2022-03-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This answer worked for me after installing the "smd" R package.