# How to reference proportions when making a custom statistic in gtsummary

Tags: gtsummary, smd

I am hoping to make a custom statistic column called Standardized Difference, which calculates the standardized mean difference for each categorical variable according to the formula: cat_smd=abs((p_1-p_0)/(sqrt(((p_1*(1-p_1)+p_0*(1-p_0))))/2)).

My challenge is that I don't know how to access/call/reference the proportions, but I know they have already been calculated in the tbl_summary. I think it involves {p}, but I don't know how to specify p_0 vs p_1. An example of some sample data and a table are below.

```r
# create data
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)


age = c(34, 26, 42, 39, 17, 32, 28, 35, 42, 42, 44, 21, 26, 19, 34, 38, 20, 23, 33, 39, 28, 30, 19, 30, 37, 22, 32, 26, 18, 26)

care = c(4, 2, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4)

sex = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)

exp = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0)

df = data.frame( age, sex, care, exp)

# create table summary
tbl = df %>%
  tbl_summary(by=exp,
              type = all_dichotomous() ~ "categorical") %>%
  add_overall() 

tbl
```

[Example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5eRY.jpg)

Desired statistic: cat_smd=abs((p_1-p_0)/(sqrt(((p_1*(1-p_1)+p_0*(1-p_0))))/2))

For example, for sex = 0, p_0 is 0.31, and p_1 is 0.50. The SMD would be 0.56.

Is anyone able to provide some advice about how to create this custom statistic?

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69401695

Comment: No, unfortunately. I am trying to get the SMDs for each level of my categorical variables without having to make them all dummy variables, so using add_difference() isn't helping me at the moment. I am hoping to access the proportions within each exposure group so that I can make a function that will calculate the SMD for each level.

Comment: Ahh ok. I think the easiest is to make the dummy. But you can use add_stat() to add any generic stat you'd like

Comment: Thanks for your help. My challenge is figuring out how to access the proportions that the summary has already calculated. Can you help me understand what term I should use in my formula for it to select the correct proportion? Something involving {p}, maybe?

Comment: Check out the details here on how to use `add_stat()` custom functions. There is a function argument in the custom function called `tbl` which is the `tbl_summary()` object. You can access the raw table statistics in the `tbl$meta_data` data frame, specifically the `df_stats` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered this at: [Add SMDs for each level of a categorical variable in gtsummary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77003690/add-smds-for-each-level-of-a-categorical-variable-in-gtsummary)

To summarise, you can use my package

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("zheer-kejlberg/Z.gtsummary.addons")
library(Z.gtsummary.addons)
```

And add SMDs for each level of categorical variables using `%>% add_SMD(location = "level")` or to get SMDs for numeric and binary variables as well `%>% add_SMD(location = "both")`

For more examples, consult https://github.com/zheer-kejlberg/Z.gtsummary.addons